# Issues while making a POST to a Web API from JQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api with the following POST Method

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string package)
```

I have a console app that uses the `HttpCLient` with no problems. When I try to make a call by means of `jQuery`, I get `null` on the package variable.

This is the code I have right now:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/Package/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(message),       
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.length);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Status: '+xhr.status+', Error Thrown: '+thrownError);

        }
    });
```

The "message" variable is a complex model containing two properties.

What could I be doing wrong?

I'll appreciate your help...

Comment: If you get nulls on your action parameters, you should *always* check the ModelState to see if there are any errors that occurred during deserialization. Do you see anything?

Comment: Does `message` have a property called `package`?

Comment: @Snixtor - No...it doesn't have a property called package

Comment: @Youssef Moussaoui - I checked the ModelState and it returned IsValid=true

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with binding the value to the response sent to the server

try sending the data as

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/Package/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { package : JSON.stringify(message) }        
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.length);

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('Status: '+xhr.status+', Error Thrown: '+thrownError);

        }
    });
```

*I am assuming that your* `JSON.stringify(message)` *returns a string value*

**updated**

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([ModelBinder]string package)
```

allowing package to bind from everywhere instead of just body did it for me.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for replying...I tried that and it didn't work. I think that I am missing something in the JQuery call...but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I updated my answer. But I am not sure whether that is the you wanted to go

Comment: Thansks for your suggestions...It is going to take some time....I'll let you know what happens...