# Can't call a Web API from jQuery script

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a litle test for a Web Api project before developing a real App. I implemented some basic `GET` action without a problem, but I have some issues with the `POST` request.
I'm calling the `POST` request with jQuery like this

```js
var data = { name: "Pedro" };
$.post({
        url: "http://localhost/Demo/api/user",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: $.stringify("="+data),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data[0].Name);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert("complete");
        }
    })
```

And my POST action is like this (on UserController.vb)

```vb
Public Function PostUser(<FromBody()> ByVal name As String) As Demo.User.Model.User
    Dim ids As Integer() = From userId In (From user In users Select user.Id)

    Dim maxId As Integer = ids.Max + 1
    Dim newUser As Demo.User.Model.User = New Demo.User.Model.User With {
        .Id = maxId, _
        .Mail = name & "@abc.com", _
        .Name = name _
    }
    users(maxId) = newUser
    Return newUser
End Function
```

With the above jQuery code I receive no error or exception message, and the action it isn't even reached. However, If I test the action from the codebehind (I'm implementing the Web Api through a Web form project) the action get called. Here is how I test from the codebehind

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Dim data As New NameValueCollection()

    data.Add("name", "Pedro")

    Dim response As Byte() = client.UploadValues("http://localhost/Demo/api/user", "POST", data)
    lbl.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response)
End Sub
```

So, my question is, why I can't reach the web Api action with my js code?

Befor you ask, I use `$.stringify("="+data),` because I extended jQuery with [this code](https://gist.github.com/chicagoworks/754454), I've done that because I need to support old versions of IE.

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823711/issues-while-making-a-post-to-a-web-api-from-jquery), with no success

**UPDATE:** I have debugged the site on Chrome and I get an [**404 error**](http://prntscr.com/74g7q8). For some reason, the data object is being sended like this `http://localhost/Demo/[object%20Object]`

Comment: Have you try to do a simple POST without parameter?

Comment: I did, with the same result, no alert, no error... nothing :(

Comment: What does `Firebug` or other browser dev tools show for the request/response?

Comment: Have you tried to add the [HttpPost] attribute to the PostUser method?

Comment: And, please put `alert("success");` before `alert(data[0].Name);` - you might being getting invalid data and not be aware of it.

Comment: @Dusan I have debugged the site on Chrome and I get an [`404 error`](http://prntscr.com/74g7q8). For some reason, the data object is being sended like this   **`http://localhost/Demo/[object%20Object]`**

Comment: Have you tried using `"=" + $.stringify(data)` instead of `$.stringify("="+data)` because it looks like the stringify method from that referenced code is wrapping everything you pass in in quotes. so the output is probably `'"=mydata"'` not `='"mydata"'`. The comments on that github page also mention some other bugs in the code.... you might want to try JSON.stringify()

Comment: @Arkaine55 I changed as you suggested and get the same 404 error, I'll update my question

Comment: @Dusan I would like to say that you are right, but that didn't work. I tried with `data: data` and `data: "="+data` and I receive the same error, and the same Url structure

Comment: How about removing `<FromBody()>`, does it work with `data: data`?

Comment: have you tried **localhost:PORTNUMBER**

Comment: Try removing `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"`

Comment: I've tried all that you said in comments with the same results. @saj As I said in my question, I use jQuery.stringify because some olde versions of IE doesn't support JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my Issue but still don't quite understand it. Looking at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), I've found that the `data` option in the `$.post()` call is for `GET` request

> data Type: PlainObject or String or Array Data to be sent to the
>   server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.
>   **It's appended to the url for GET-requests**. See processData option to
>   prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If
>   value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

So I changed my code to the [first option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) of the `$.post()` call

```
var data = { Name: "Pedro", Mail: "peter@mail.com" };
$.post("http://localhost/Demo/api/user", data, function (d) { alert(d);}, "json")
```

That actually solved my problem, but I'm not quite happy with the solution, because, as mentioned in jquery docs, the `data` attribute change it's behavior depending on the method call so I though that it should be fine as I was before... If any one can clarify this would be awesome :)

Comment: You are misunderstanding the docs. In GET requests there is no payload, so the data has to be sent appended to the url. But in POST requests the data it's send as the payload (body) of the request, in formdata format by default, or as JSON with the right configuration.